# C++ Start Driver kernel: Access Denied

Tags: c++, драйвер, kernel

Помогите с драйвером.

отключил цифровую подпись при загрузке системы, включил тестовый режим, выключил проверку цифровой подписи в групповой политике, запускал от администратора, создавал тестовый сертификат (вручную и через VS) и указывал места прописи вручную и автоматически = ERROR CODE: 1275 (Access Denied);

КАК ЗАПУСТИТЬ СВОЙ ДРАЙВЕР?????????? WINDOWS 10

```
void install_NDIS_driver() 
{
    SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
    if (hSCManager == NULL) printf("OpenSCManager Failed with error code: %i\n",GetLastError());
    else printf("OpenSCManager Sucessfully\n");
    SC_HANDLE mService = CreateService(hSCManager, "TESTDRIVER", "TESTDRIVER", SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, "C:\\Users\\Exidios\\source\\repos\\TESTDRIVER\\x64\\Release\\TESTDRIVER.sys", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    SC_HANDLE mOpenService = OpenService(hSCManager, "TESTDRIVER", SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (mOpenService == NULL) 
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        printf("OpenService Failed with error code: %i\n",GetLastError());
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Sucessfully OpenService\n");
        BOOL b = StartServiceA(mOpenService, NULL, NULL);
        if (!b) printf("fail StartServiceA: %i\n",GetLastError());  
        else printf("StartServiceA sucessfully\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Предлагаете угадать в котором из четырех мест у вас ошибка выводится?

Comment: Я же сказал, Acess Denied на запуск драйвера. (1275); 

"if (!b) printf("fail StartServiceA: %i\n",GetLastError()); "

Comment: Где же вы это сказали? У меня к ночи глаза устали, не вижу. Независимо от этого категорически рекомендую почитать про возвращаемое значение CreateService и посмотреть как вы его в коде проверяете.

Comment: Ой, перед отправкой сюда забыл удалить лишнее. Простите. Я про это имел ввиду: Где идёт:

printf("Sucessfully OpenService\n");
BOOL b = StartServiceA(mOpenService, NULL, NULL);

На StartServiceA выдает по непонятным причинам ERROR CODE (1275: ACCESS DENIED) хотя цифровую подпись отключил, включил тестовый режим, отключил в групповой политике проверку цифровой подписи, сделал тестовую цифровую подпись и так далее, но всё равно эта ошибка есть и я уже голову сломал над ней.

Comment: Так кто-то знает как запустить свой драйвер не прибегая к Windows 7?